# Significance of order of interfaces

Tags: c#

I have a compile problem that I don't understand. I'm going to generify the code to make it simpler to follow and I hope I don't lose the meaning.  The error is:

```
MyInterface1 does not contain definition for 'MyClass1'
```

which is correct because `MyClass1` is in `MyInterface2`.
If I switch the order of the interfaces like so:

```
public partial class MyPresenter : ParentPresenter<MyInterface2>, ParentPresenter<MyInterface1>
```

then it compiles. What is going on here?

First file:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public partial class MyPresenter :  ParentPresenter<MyInterface1>, ParentPresenter<MyInterface2>
    {

        public MyClass1 MyClass1 { get; set; }

        public void MyMethod() {
            View.MyClass1 = this.MyClass1; // compile error on View.MyClass1

      }
    }
}
```

Second File:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public interface MyInterface1
    {
        System.Collections.IList MyList1 { set; }
    }

    public interface MyInterface2
    {
        MyClass1 MyClass1 { set; }

        System.Collections.IList MyList2 { set; }
    }
}
```

file3:

```
public abstract class ParentPresenter<TView> : System.IDisposable
{
    private TView _view;
    private Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.WorkItem _workItem;

    public TView View
    {
        get { return this._view; }
        set
        {
            this._view = value;
            this.OnViewSet();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: add setter to MyClass1

Comment: I'm not sure why it sometimes compiles and sometimes not, but shouldn't the MyClass1 field in MyInterface2 be a property?

Comment: Related: "[*Prefix interface names with the letter I, to indicate that the type is an interface.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bc1fexb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)"

Comment: What is `View`? It's where your error is, and it's the **only** thing you haven't defined in the whole question

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that you've named your class type as well as your instance `MyClass1`. But, I'm not sure why it would compile conditionally on how the interfaces are ordered if that was the problem.

Comment: @adv12:  added more code on your suggestion

Comment: @Jcl:  added more code on your suggestion

Comment: @AlLelopath now the problem is obvious, I've added an answer

Comment: `MyPresenter :  ParentPresenter<MyInterface1>, ParentPresenter<MyInterface2>` is multiple inheritance (of classes), which C# doesn't allow. What you should do is make sure that without the `View.MyClass1 = this.MyClass1;` line it compiles. It seems like it shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is obvious after the edit.

You are doing:

```
public partial class MyPresenter :  ParentPresenter<MyInterface1>
```

So that means your class inherits from:

```
public abstract class ParentPresenter<TView> : System.IDisposable
```

Where `TView` is a `MyInterface1`.

So, your `View` property is now of type `MyInterface1`, which doesn't have a definition for `MyClass1`, thus the compiler error where you try to access `View.MyClass1`

This:

```
public partial class MyPresenter :  
           ParentPresenter<MyInterface1>, 
           ParentPresenter<MyInterface2>
```

Is not supported by C#, that's multiple inheritance. It's only allowed for interfaces, but not for classes (in the original question you were implementing two interfaces, which is supported: after the edit you are trying to inherit from two classes, which is not).

You could however do something like:

```
public interface MyInterface3 : MyInterface1, MyInterface2
{
}
```

And then you could do:

```
public partial class MyPresenter : ParentPresenter<MyInterface3>
```

This would mean your `View` would have to implement both interfaces (`MyInterface1` and `MyInterface2`), and be declared as implementing `MyInterface3` (C# doesn't support duck-typing either), but by the looks of it, it already does implement everything necessary

Comment: I understand now. I find it strange that the line that has the multiple inheritance does not have a compile error being as multiple inheritance is not allowed.

Comment: Note that interfaces can not inherit, but they are allowed to implement other interfaces

Comment: @AlLelopath You may encounter this if another error prevents the compiler from getting far enough to realize that you've attempted to inherit from two different classes.

Comment: Oh, yes that makes sense.